# Conversions in amines

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

We have to find A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H.
I got C is acetophenone and D is benzoic acid and further I got what are  E,F,G,H
I am just a bit confused in A and B please any hints..

Edits : C is acetophenone and the reagent in first reaction where A and B are reactants is AlCl3 not H2O
[image: conversion from amines]

Comment: There's not enough information to answer this unambiguously. A could be benzyl alcohol and B an oxidising agent but there are other possibilities.

Comment: Or -- as an alternative to the oxidation suggested by `@Waylander` -- a Grignard reaction of $\ce{PhMgBr}$ and, e.g., ethyl formate.

Comment: Sorry ,C will be acetophenone I think now ,if I am wrong do correct me

Comment: @Rover _If_ the entry about «2,4-DNP» is about 2,4-dinitrophenylhydrazine, then this may react on either aldehyde, or cetone ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,4-Dinitrophenylhydrazine#Brady's_test)). This then requires a cross check in a database (e.g., Reaxys) or/and table (e.g. [CRC Handbook Of Tables For Organic Compound Identification](https://archive.org/details/crc-handbook-of-tables-for-organic-compound-identification-3rd-ed./page/n151/mode/2up)) if your diagram is supported by experimental evidence.  We got colored hands preparing derivative hydrazones, picrates, etc.

Comment: There still is not enough information to identify A&B if C is acetophenone. The range of possible reactants just got wider.

Comment: So if the conditions of the first reaction are AlCl3 then we are looking at a Friedel-Crafts reaction with benzene and acetyl  hloride

Answer (score 5):

As @Waylander mentioned in comments, more information is needed to guess A and B.

Since, in the question other products have not been mentioned, I am writing the answers for them with reasoning.

**1)** Since on reaction of D with soda lime gives benzene, which is a decarboxylating reaction, we guess that D should be benzoic acid or sodium benzoate as you have correctly guessed.

**2)** Now we see that C on reaction with $\ce{NaOH}+\ce{Br_2}$ gives benzoic acid, and as the mentioned reagents are reagents for iodoform reaction, we conclude that C must have been a methyl ketone and hence acetophenone which also gives 2,4-DNP test.

**3)** Now D i.e, benzoic acid on heating with $\ce{NH_3}$ gives benzamide which is a condensation reaction in which water condenses out. So, E is benzamide.

**4)** Benzamide on reaction with $\ce{NaOH}+\ce{Br_2}$ will give aniline, which is the [Hoffmann Bromamide degradation reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofmann_rearrangement). So,F is aniline.

**5)** Aniline on reaction with $\ce{CHCl_3}+\ce{KOH}$ will give phenyl isocynaide which is the [carbylamine reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbylamine_reaction).

**6)** Ozonolysis of phenyl isocyanide gives phenyl isocyanate. So, H is phenyl isocyanate.

---

Were there any options in the question from where this has been asked? If there were, it would make it easy to guess A and B.